# Is there a way to introduce a separator in socket reception?

Tags: c#, sockets, separator

I'm working with C# socket communication, and I receive different messages, separated by a special character (`ASCII code 3`).

Currently this is not taken into account and my setup of the reception, who looks as follows:

```
sock.BeginReceive(_receivedData, 
                  0, 
                  _receivedData.Length, 
                  SocketFlags.None, 
                  OnReceivedData, 
                  sock);
```

This receives different messages, separated by the mentioned character, as one message.

Inside of the `OnReceivedData(...)` I can run through the whole received bytearray, and look for that special character myself, but I would prefer having this handled by the socket handler itself.

Does anybody know how to declare the callback receive in order to take a separator into account, something like (pseudo-code):

```
sock.BeginReceive(_receivedData, 
                  0, 
                  _receivedData.Length, 
                  SocketFlags.None, // maybe here?
                  OnReceivedData, 
                  sock, 
                  separator=chr(3));
```

**Edit after some more investigation**

The "complete" code concerning the reception of the data looks as follows:

```
private void SetupReceiveCallback(Socket sock)
{  try
     { sock.BeginReceive(_receivedData, 0, _receivedData.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceivedData, sock);}
   catch (Exception ex)
     { }
}

private void OnReceivedData(IAsyncResult ar)
{  sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

   // Check if we got any data
   try
     {
        int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar);
```

This (`sock.BeginReceive()`takes in a whole bunch of data at once, while I would like the data being taken up to a certain character (`0x03`), which is the terminator of my message.

My own answer is wrong indeed, as it takes data, which are not even complete, causing a mess (as predicted by [Dialectus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395718/dialecticus)).
As far as the proposal from [Panagiatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos): I'm very new at C# programming. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just wish arbitrary software features into existence :)

Comment: Yes, TCP is an endless stream of bytes and if you want messages, it's up to *you* to implement that (or move to a higher level protocol that does do messages). Don't think of the call to `Receive` as "getting one message", because that's *not what the protocol promised*.

Comment: The `Socket` class has a method named `ReceiveMessageFrom` and the equivalent APM method, [BeginReceiveMessageFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivemessagefrom?view=net-5.0) that only reads a specific number of bytes. That's no accident. With a stream of bytes, that's the only way you can define a message. You'll have to read the bytes in that buffer to determine whether they contain the character you want

Comment: Sockets are the transport layer of your communication link over which you implement your protocol layer (where in your caseeach message is delimited by an ASCII code 3 byte).

Comment: Whether you read bytes one by one and inspect them, or read a buffer at a time and inspect it to find out message boundaries, you'll end up with complex code. You should consider using Pipelines. As the [basic socket example shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#pipe-basic-usage) the code is still relatively complex *but* memory usage is a LOT better due to the reuse of buffers from a buffer pool, and the behavior of pipes. All you'd have to do is replace `\n` with `\x03` in the example

Comment: Split message by a special flag is not safe. Define your own protocol rely on TCP might be a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the many comments, immediately after having posted the question, a separator cannot be declared in the communication part of my application: I just have to get everything coming from the socket, and do the separation myself, which I did like this:

```
string [] infoList = infoString.Split('\u0003');
foreach (string infoEntry in infoList)
{
    ... // do the treatment of the messages, one by one
```

Comment: That's definitely *not* what you should do. How are you going to get the bytes from the socket into the string in the first place? Using strings instead of buffers will generate a *lot* of temporary strings too, wasting both RAM and CPU time in allocation *and* garbage collection. You'll lose *any* benefit you'd get by using sockets. It would be faster to use a `NetworkStream` and a `StreamReader` at this point

Comment: There is a problem that you may receive half a message, or two halves of different messages. You should have a buffer with unfinished message, append new bytes to that buffer, and in while loop remove first message and the ending 0x03, until there are no more 0x03 in the buffer. Some text may remain in the buffer, and you are waiting for 0x03 that will end the message, so you can process it. This 0x03 must be a TERMINATOR, and not a SEPARATOR. Otherwise you wont know if you received a complete message.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: although I understand the idea you're saying, I don't know how to implement it. Therefore I've started a bounty on this question.

Comment: @Dialecticus: You're right: I have already incomplete messages, causing a message, hence I've started a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 4):

This separator is part of your communication protocol. Sockets do not know anything about applicative protocols. They only know about TCP/IP. Therefore there is no way to have this handled by the framework. You must handle it. You call this character a separator, but it must be actually a terminator. Your protocol must provide the information when the message is ending, otherwise you will not know if you received a complete message.

You are provided with stream of bytes, and the only guarantee you have is that if the stream exists then it has the same bytes, in the same order, as they were sent. You may not receive all bytes, and there is no guarantee that you will. Your communication protocol must be good enough to detect when a new message is started in the stream, and when it is ending.

Or you can adopt some existing communication protocol, and the library that implements it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any callback ever implement packet processing.
You need to under stand separation of interest task of stream reader is delivery of  payload (bytes).

As you mentioned separator 0x03, actually this is ETX (end of text) which indicates end of data at end of any packet. But in your case multiple messages are stacked together by ETX.

Unless you follow standard protocol (Ymodem, Kermit, Modbus) its highly depends on implementers.

A good packet protocol shall include start of text (0x02), number of bytes, payload data, checksum and end of text (0x03).

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use a NetworkStream to access your data.

[NetworkStream.ReadByte() method on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readbyte?view=net-5.0)

NetworkStream constructor accepts Socket as an argument.  You can read one byte at a time to consume a message, without discarding any data unintentionally.  I believe (not sure) it will also buffer internally for you.  I don't think there is an async version of this method so you must also take this into account; from your code provided it's not clear to me whether that would have a major impact.